# Can you use more than one < in an if condition?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Is it ok to have an if condition with more than one "less than" (<) or "greater than" (>) symbol in it?

For example, I usually see if conditions written like this:
`if( x > 7 && x < 14)`
but could you instead write it like this?
`if( 7 < x < 14 )`

The second way compiles but I'm not sure if there are any drawbacks or unexpected results from doing it that way.

Comment: Have you tried running it? Does it give you the expected result?

Comment: Short answer *No*, try it and read the compiler errors/warnings... If you add parens, you will end up with an expression that is always true or false.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you can. But it will give you something that is not equivalent to the same expression as in mathematics (or the first `&&` expression).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have compiled it but did not see the warning.  I just checked and found it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` at minimum (on Linux) and `/Wall` on windoze. The compiler with point out the ambiguity and the result of any attempt to fix it. (although the gcc warnings and errors are far superior to what you will get on windoze)

Comment: @tkausl Wanted to run it but I'm working on an embedded platform and can't currently flash the controller.

Comment: relevant warning: `comparisons like X<=Y<=Z do not have their mathematical meaning`

Comment: You could write it `if (7 < x && x < 14)` if you wanted to.

Comment: @RichardChambers Thanks, I think that's the closest you can get to how it is written in math and it still works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write  `if( 7 < x < 14 ) something;` but that's basically a long-winded way of saying `something`.

`7 < x < 14` will be interpreted as `(7<x) < 14`, and `7<x` will be either `0` or `1`, both of which are less than `14`, and therefore the condition will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

You can. It will simply compare the Boolean value from (7 < x) with 14 resulting in a true condition. Always!